# Уязвимости проброса портов для сервера Node.js

Tags: node.js, безопасность, порты

У меня появился вопрос насчёт безопасности проброса портов на роутере. У меня есть белый IP адресс, и сервер на Node.js, который работает на определенном порту. Я делаю проброс портов на роутере, указывая локальный адресс компьютера (напр. `192.168.#.#`) и порт, на котором запущен сервер node.js.

Что представляет из себя этот сервер - Я написал небольшой чат, к которому можно подключиться указав пароль, если пароль верный, пропускаю, если нет, не пропускаю.

Так вот, я читал статьи в интернете, там говорилось что при пробросе портов нужно быть осторожным, и не открывать порты к важным программам, а если открыли, то обязательно установить пароль. Так же рекомендуют спрятать порт за VPN, но я не совсем понимаю как это сделать.

Буду раз если кто-то расскажет об возможных уязвимостях такого метода, и как от них защититься. Добавлю, что чат я создал на некоторое время, исключительно для себя и знакомых. Благодарю заранее !)

Comment: Если вы пробрасываете только один порт, то потенциальная уязвимость это ваш сервер не ноде, к другим портам просто не будет доступа. И да, вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, спасибо за ответ, да, ответ общий. Сервер просто слушает порт, и возвращает какой-то результат в зависимости от запроса. Хотел просто узнать есть ли уязвимости помимо самого сервера.

Comment: Побаловаться для себя можно и пробросом порта. Но по хорошему внутренние сервера (backend) ставят за обратным прокси (reverse proxy) например HAProxy или Nginx. В этом случае получается, что сервера полностью изолированы от внешнего интернета и "общаются" только через прокси.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, да, верно говорите. Мой сервер работает на виртуальной машине, debian, nginx настроен тоже там. Думаю, так даже безопаснее.